# What are the rate limits for the Google Books API?

Tags: python, google-api, http-status-code-429, google-books-api

I'm interested in doing around 12K total ISBN queries to find books' categories. However, I get an HTTP error 429 and when trying to sort it out, I couldn't find any info on the limit of requests (per second, per minute, per hour, etc).

Does anyone know the rate limits for the Google Books API?

Comment: You can just handle in your code. When you get a 429 error, back-off for a bit, pause or slow down the requests, then retry again. While there might be a limit defined somewhere, hardcoding it is not maintainable.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Google Book API Error "429 Client Error: Too Many Requests for url"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69935318/google-book-api-error-429-client-error-too-many-requests-for-url)

Answer (score 0):

You can see your current quota for any api you have enabled in your project on [Google cloud console](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/api/books.googleapis.com/quotas)

Library -> search for the api -> click manage -> quota tab

Default seems to be

[image]

There are two types of quotas.  Project based and user based.

The project based quota covers all your users and its counted against your project itself.

User based quotas will depend upon the user using your system. It would require that you send quotaUser or userIp with your request.  This is basically flood protection.